# How to match and then replace only a part of an entire line in RegEx while preserving certain part(s) in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I'd like to replace line-by-line in a file with Notepad++ like this:

```
EE_START_RESEARCH;Start researching %s.;STUFF;STUFF;STUFF;STUFF;STUFF;;;;;X
```

to

```
EE_START_RESEARCH;Start researching %s.;;;;;;;;;;X
```

Preserving the first bit before the first semicolon and the same with the part between the first and the second semicolon. The semicolon being the delimiter here.

I tried these:

Find: `^(.*)$` Replace: `"\1";;;;;;;;;;X`

Find: `^(.+)$` Replace: `"\1";;;;;;;;;;X`

Find: `^(.+)$` Replace: `(\1);(\1);;;;;;;;;;X`

Find: `^(.*)$` Replace: `(\1);(\1);;;;;;;;;;X`

Any hints? Thanks in advance!

PS. If it helps, the files are .CSVs from Hearts of Iron II game. I need to remove the other languages and leave English only (and it's in the first 'column').

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^EE_START_RESEARCH;Start researching %s\.\K.+?(X)$`
- Replace with: `;;;;;;;;;;$1`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>
- <kbd>Search in document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       : beginning of line
  EE_START_RESEARCH;Start researching %s\.
  \K    : forget all we have seen until this position
  .+?   : 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
  (X)   : group 1
$       : end of line
```

**Result for given example:**

```
EE_START_RESEARCH;Start researching %s.;;;;;;;;;;X
```

Comment: It's obvious I stated my editing intentions wrong. However, using the info about groups from this reply I managed to achieve what I wanted, after all. I used `(` and `)` to capture the respective groups, then replaced them with `$1` and `$2` commands, filling the rest with `;;;;;;;;;;X`.

Comment: @Aletta: It's not really clear what you want to do. Why do you want 2 capture groups where only one is needed? What's wrong with my regex?